# constructing a std::vector using std::transform. Possibility to return unnamed result?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

Let's have

```
class InputClass; 
class OutputClass; 

OutputClass const In2Out(InputClass const &in)
{
    //conversion implemented
}
```

and finally

```
std::vector<OutputClass> Convert(std::vector<InputClass> const &input)
{
    std::vector<OutputClass> res;
    res.reserve(input.size());
    //either 
    for (auto const &in : input)
        res.emplace_back(In2Out(in));
    return res;
    //or something like
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(res), [](InputClass const &in){return In2Out(in);});
    return res;
}
```

And now **my question**:

Can I rewrite the Convert function somehow *avoiding the need to name the new container*? I. e. is there a way to construct a vector directly using something roughly like std::transform or std::for_each?

As in (pseudocode, this unsurprisingly does not work or even build)

```
std::vector<OutputClass> Convert(std::vector<InputClass> const &input)
{
    return std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(std::vector<OutputClass>()), [](InputClass const &in){return In2Out(in);});
}
```

Searched, but did not find any elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Would a solution which is more awkward but satisfies the "unnamed container" be helpful, or are you just wondering if you missed an idiomatic way to simplify?

Comment: [Off Topic] `OutputClass const &In2Out(InputClass const &in)` is more than likely not correct.  You cannot return a reference to a function local object.  Doing so is undefined behavior.

Comment: @aschepler: both actually. I started wondering about simplification and ended up on "there must be some way, be it an awkward one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and quite simple when using boost:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
};

std::vector<B> Convert(const std::vector<A> &input)
{
    auto trans = [](const A&) { return B{}; };
    return { boost::make_transform_iterator(input.begin(), trans), boost::make_transform_iterator(input.end(), trans) };
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZSqt2SbsHeY8V0mt

But as other mentioned this is weird and doesn't provide any gain (no performance gain or readability gain)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I won't use it (as you say, no gain), but it is precisely what I was searching for. I'll accept this answer later unless there is yet a better one:)

Answer (score 3):

Starting in C++ 20 you can use the new `std::ranges::transform_view` to accomplish what you want.  It will call your transformation function for each element in the container that it is adapting and you can use that view to invoke `std::vector`'s iterator range constructor which will allocate the memory for the entire vector once and then populate the elements.  It still requires you to create a variable in the function but it becomes much more streamlined.  That would give you something like

```
std::vector<OutputClass> Convert(std::vector<InputClass> const &input)
{
    auto range = std::ranges::transform_view(input, In2Out);
    return {range.begin(), range.end()};
}
```

---

Do note that this should optimize to the exact same code your function generates.

Comment: And range-v3 has `to_vector` to really don't use named temporary.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I rewrite the Convert function somehow avoiding the need to name the new container?

Not using just `std::transform`. `std::transform` itself never creates a container. It only inserts elements to an output iterator. And in order to both get output iterator to a container, and return the container later, you pretty much need a name (unless you allocate the container dynamically, which would be silly and inefficient).

You can of course write a function that uses `std::transform`, creates the (named) vector, and returns it. Then caller of that function doesn't need to care about that name. In fact, that's pretty much what your function `Convert` is.